# Angular material expansion panel losing background when expanded

Tags: css, angular, hover, angular7

I am using angular 7 and material expansion panel in my project. In css I changed the color of the header both on and without hover. When I expand the panel the hover is working but when I leave the header it loses color.

before

[image]

and after

[image]

css

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header::after {
    padding: 10;
    background-color:#E03616;
    color:white;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .mat-expansion-panel-header {
    padding: 10;
    background-color:#E03616;
    color:white;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .disable_ripple:hover{
    background: #E03616 !important;
    }
```

html

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
      <mat-expansion-panel-header class='disable_ripple .disable_ripple_a'>
        Test Exams
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>

      <div *ngFor='let c of noCases; let j = index' style="padding:1em;" class="main-div">
          <button mat-raised-button (click)='examselected(c.examid)' color='primary'>Exam {{j+1}}</button>
      </div>

    </mat-expansion-panel>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add CSS changes you did to change color

Comment: Can you please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Would you create an example on the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)